# Adding an element to vector inside a vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector

Simply, I have a vector:

```
vector<vector<int>> myvector
```

For this example it would look like this:

```
myvector[
vector{1,2,3}
vector{1,2,3,4,5}
vector{1,2}
]
```

How would one go about adding a number such as 4 to the first vector inside myvector to make it look like below?:

```
myvector[
vector{1,2,3,4}
vector{1,2,3,4,5}
vector{1,2}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
myvector[0].push_back(4);
```

Comment: Thanks Remy, it turns out this is what I was doing but you can't push back onto an empty double vector in this way. Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: @Dave you have to add an inner vector to `myvector` so `myvector.size() > 0` before you can then access `myvector[0]`

Answer (score 0):

you can access to them with indexes:

```
vectorOne[index].push_back(1);
```

More info:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/12409/